# Tool which monitors file changes and uploads only changed files over ftp to webserver

Tags: version-control, ftp

Is there a tool(for Windows) which can monitor file changes and can upload only modified files over ftp to a webserver directory.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you need this for, some IDE's have this functionality.

Comment: I have a few html and image files in a local directoy. Whenever I modify those files, then the ftp client ( or any tool) should be able to recognize which files are modified and only those files should be syncronized with the webserver directory.

Comment: If you are using a VCS, you can use https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp to track the changes. It is not fully automatically, you have to commit changes at least...

Answer (score 0):

SmartFTP is one such tool which has synchronization feature... http://www.smartftp.com/features/